# Where is the folder for kmenuedit located in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 13.10. I often type "kmenuedit" into search in the Start menu to launch the kmenuedit program, but I'm confused as to where the kmenuedit folder is. Can anyone please tell me where it is?

Answer (score 1):

**KMenuEdit**

http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/introduction.html :

> KMenuEdit stores the menu hierarchy in
>   $HOME/.config/menus/applications-kmenuedit.menu and
>   $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories contains desktop files for
>   submenus you created. In $HOME/.local/share/applications/ you find the
>   desktop files for the custom items you created.

The executable is: /usr/bin/kmenuedit

It is installed from the package: kmenuedit - http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/kmenuedit

Desktop Menu Specification: http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/

Comment: and to see the defaults for all users, see /usr/share/applications